# paginate ng-repeat items which are filtered using filter:query

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to filter|query on a list of items in angular which are paginated.

The problem is the filter|query works only on the paginated items, but I would like to paginate only the filtered items, rather than vice-versa.

For example:

1. list of items
2. paginate
3. if filtered, then paginate the filtered items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own filter, check if the data passed to the item is paginated and then apply your filter algorithm.

```
myModule.filter('filterOnlyPaginated', function() {
return function(data) {
  if(data.isPaginated()) {
    return data....
  }
  else {
    return data;
  }
}});
```

EDIT:
Maybe limitTo is usefull https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id | filter:query | limitTo:10">{{item.name}}</div>
```

2nd EDIT:
Use

```
<div ng-repeat="item in filterFunction(items)"></div>
```

filterFunction is:

```
.controller('yourController', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.filterFunction = function(items) {
        return $filter('filterName')(items);
    };
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Could you please elaborate on to check if the data passed to the item is paginated ?

Comment: Could you explain better your main question ?

Comment: I have a list of items, on which I want to use filter:query and on the filtered items paginate. I am new to Angular, if I may add.

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: I think what I need to do, is load filtered data into the ng-repeat.

Comment: Well, <div ng-repeat="item in filterFunction(items)"></div> where filterFunction is in your scope

Comment: This is looking better, Is it possible to use filter:query inside this custom function to filter items ?